# Can you help me install Windows 7 from bootable USB?

Tags: windows-7, installation

i just bought Acer Aspire E15 and it has no system preinstalled. I have an USB containing Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit and i made it bootable by YUMI software. The problem is that when i power on the computer i get a windows with two options, Linpus Linux Create a bootable USB drive When i plug the usb it imediatly starts the linpus linux and gets to root@localhost and just stays there. If i choose the other one it says import the USB bla bla it will delete your files, you have to say yes and it just drops lines that are identical to forever...What is wrong?
If you need more details please say so and as you help i can also post pictures for you to see whats happening..

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062 just use Rufus

Comment: Use the F12 key to enter the one time boot menu, then select your usb device to boot from.... http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6814/~/enabling-the-boot-device-menu

Comment: Your question's hard to read as written. Can you edit it for spelling and grammar?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the flash drive using the official Windows USB Download Tool and see if you're able to install using the resulting flash drive: http://wudt.codeplex.com/

Comment: When i do that am i just to plug it in as i power on the laptop?

Comment: Yes, you'll need another Windows computer to create the flash drive on then plug it in and turn the computer on

Comment: Im downloading it..but it says it makes iso into bootable USB but i have all my files extracted out of iso and put into USB..what now?

Comment: You will need an ISO. Possibly part of the problem is where ever you've retrieved your files from didn't copy everything completely

Comment: I have found an original iso i used to create the USB and will delete everything off of this USB and create a new one using the software you provided. Just so id know, what if the same thing happens when i plug in, that is what if nothing happens?

Comment: We'll go from there. Could be BIOS/UEFI settings. Some motherboards don't like booting from USB and some USB drives don't work well or at all for booting off of (I've had problems with those ultra cheap ones that hand out free at events, etc). Name brand USB drives usually work fine (I've had good luck with Sandisk and PNY)